# What's the best alternative to an out of control switch statement?

Tags: c#, javascript, refactoring, switch-statement

I have inherited a project that has some huge switch statement blocks, with some containing up to 20 cases.  What is a good way to rewrite these?

Comment: How much code duplication is there between the blocks?

Answer (score 16):

Why would you want to rewrite them in a different structure?  If you really have 20 cases that have to be handled individually, a switch/case is the way to go.  A big chain of if/then logic would be horrible to maintain.

Polymorphism is another option if you are using an object-oriented language.  Each subclass would implement it's own functionality in the method.

Comment: So much for polymrorphism, eh?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the there is a point in code where 20 different things can happen, not that there is a switch statement.  I switch statement is the best construct for this ugly situation.

Comment: If the code is written in C or some other non-OO language then polymorphism isn't really an option.

Comment: And now I see that this question has C# and Javascript tags.  In C# I'd consider polymorphism.  In Javascript OO is such an abomination that I'd just keep the switch/case :P

Comment: I agree, I have one project that's just one massive `switch` statement - works fine for me.

Comment: Even with polymorphism, wouldn't that still not eliminate the need for the switch? You'd still need a switch inside of a factory to select the correct implementation. it would however eliminate all of the logic from the switch and abstract it to a factory instead of having it in your main flow. I only bring this up because I see this polymorphism answer a lot but never with an example.

Answer (score 6):

Polymorphism. But it may not be a trivial refactoring.

Some examples and refs:

[Refactoring (Googe books)](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=1MsETFPD3I0C&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=Polymorphism+switch+statement&source=web&ots=pKO-k1YCdd&sig=PD19V8Revm2kwRQk2yF8bF9wGPs&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=7&ct=result)

[Switch Statement code smell and Polymorphism](http://hanuska.blogspot.com/2006/08/swich-statement-code-smell-and.html)

[Refactoring switch-statements](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/switch-statements)

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out, it depends on the switch statement. However, in the past I have refactored switch statements by proceeding in the following way. Suppose we have a switch statement like this, with a lot of repeating code

```
switch(x){
   case 1:
     makeitso("foo");
     globalLog += "foo";
   case 2:
     makeitso("bar");
     globalLog += "bar";
   case 3:
     makeitso("baz");
     globalLog += "baz";
   ...
   default:
      throw("input error");
}
```

the first thing to do is to recognize the parts that are common (in the real world, this will probably be a *little* more substantial)

```
makeitso([some string]);
globalLog += [some string];
```

and turn that into a function

```
function transformInput(somestring) {
     makeitso(somestring);
     globalLog += somestring;
}
```

then for the parts that change in each case, use a hash or an array;

```
var transformvalues = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
```

from here we can do this:

```
var tvals = ["foo", "bar", "baz" ... ];
function transformInput(somestring) {
     makeitso(somestring);
     globalLog += somestring;
}
var tval = tvals[x];
if(tval!==undefined) {
     transformInput(tval);
} else {
    throw ("invalid input");
}
```

And with tvals factored out of the switch statement, it could even be provided externally to expand the number of cases you can handle. Or you could build it dynamically. In the real world, the switch statement will often have special cases, however. I leave that as an excercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

Three suggestions (echoing some already given):

1. Maybe a switch isn't as bad as you think. It can be ugly if the case blocks are large. Shorten them by extracting the logic into methods.
2. In an OO language, polymorphism might be the answer, as many have pointed out.
3. In a functional language, like Javascript, write a function that returns the function you need to run for whatever input. That might use a switch statement itself, or it might use a lookup table.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with having 20 cases in a switch statement. You can tidy the code by refactoring and, at the very least, move the case processing into methods/functions.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what the switch statement is evaluating, you may want to refactor it using the Strategy Pattern.  Take a look at [this post](http://jeremyjarrell.com/archive/2007/10/28/64.aspx) for an example of replacing a switch on enum values with separate classes to handle each function.

It also may be that using the switch with 20 cases may actually be the best course of action for it.  As long as it's readable and each result clearly conveys what the action is there's no need to really refactor it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think you should refactor only when you need to, such as when you want to add more features, but the current design isn't up for the task. You should then refactor without adding the new functionality, and only then add the new feature.

In other circumstances, don't bother with refactoring. Do it when you need to, otherwise there are probably more important things to do.

If you really really need to, then the [Visitor Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is a common switch-case replacement, though you should note it does have drawbacks. (i.e., check out [www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the switch statement is doing.

If it's matching characters or strings, say in a parser, and you don't have the same set of patterns repeated everywhere in the code, then a switch statement might be ok.

If it's matching (say) an integer against a list of allowed values, you can create a base class and a set of derived classes for each value. Then, whatever generates the integer data in the first place can create an instance of the derived class with all of the switch statement "answers" instead.

A third option is to create a data structure that maps patterns to actions (i.e., functions or objects with virtual methods). You can look up the switch value in this data strucutre, and execute the appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

if it's working without major bugs (by not major I mean they don't make you pull your hair out) why bother refactor it? Don't refactor everything.

If you want, you can change it to polymorphism, but this will be a shotgun surgery, you'll probably have to refactor a whole lot more than just this switch block.

Answer (score -1):

Visit https://github.com/Pedram-Ahmadpour/Switch-Case

### Client side

Create an instance of your **Condition**, then pass a condition to **Condition** object by *Switch()* function.

```
    int sense = 2;
    ConditionSense conditionSense = new ConditionSense();
    conditionSense.Switch(sense);
```

### Server side

1. Create a *condition action*. This interface defines how to execute a **Condition**.

   ```
   public interface IAction
   {
       void Do();
   }
   ```
2. Create list of cases you want. These classes must implement *condition action* and **ICase**; Keep them light.

   ```
       public class CaseCry : IAction, ICase<int?>
       {
           public int? Key { get { return 2; } }

           public void Do()
           {
               Sense.Cry cry = new Sense.Cry();
               cry.Act();
           }
       }
   ```

   - **ICase** just holds a **Key** that it is used by *Switch()* function to navigate the cases.

     ```
     public interface ICase<TCase>
     {
         TCase Key { get; }
     }
     ```
3. Create a **Condition** class that it Inherites **SwitchCase** generic abstract class.

   - Add all cases witch you want to **Cases** property.
   - Define a *Switch()* function and navigate **Cases** property to find matches cases, then execute them as a *condition action*.

     ```
     public class ConditionSense : SwitchCase<int?>
     {
         public ConditionSense()
         {
             Cases = new List<ICase<int?>>
             {
                 new CaseSmile(),
                 new CaseCry()
             };

             DefaultCases = new List<ICase<int?>> {
                 new CaseNoSense()
             };
         }

         public void Switch(int? key)
         {
             IEnumerable<IAction> matches = Cases.Where(p => p.Key.Equals(key))
                 .Select(p => p as IAction);
             if (matches.Count() > 0)
                 foreach (IAction match in matches)
                     match.Do();
             else
                 foreach (IAction defaultCase in DefaultCases)
                     defaultCase.Do();
         }
     }
     ```

**Smile**, **Cry**..., can be huge, don't worry about size of them; *condition action* and **ICase** keep them lazy load.

```
        public class Sense
        {
            public class Smile
            {
                public void Act()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm smiling :-)");
                }
            }

            public class Cry
            {
                public void Act()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm crying :-(");
                }
            }

            public class NoSense
            {
                public void Act()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I've no sense :-|");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This answer relies almost completely on the content of external links. Should they ever become invalid, your answer would be useless. So please [edit] your answer and add at least a summary of how this approach works. Thank you!